# Add stylesheetclass to telerik dropdown

Tags: telerik

I want to add a CSS class to telerik dropdown. Here is my View Code:

```
@Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Name("ddlSalutationMailing").Items((ddlItem => { ddlItem.Add().Text(" - Select One - "); }))
```

Purpose:

I have many Telerik dropdownlists in my project, So I would like to set width commonly for all dropdownlists.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If Telerik doesn't have a method allowing you to set attributes on the dropdownlist, what I commonly do is look at the underlying HTML, find the CSS classes that Telerik uses to represent the dropdownlist, and override the width values with the values you want.  That's worked well for me for what you are describing.

Comment: Hi Brain

Thanks for your answer. If I change the width values of Telerik dropdown CSS It will affect all the Telerik dropdowns in my application. So It would be better If I set CSS on my own.